# How to pass a simple integer parameter in HTTP GET request?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have the following code in my component, which is supposed to send an id to the WebApiController and fetch back some data. But I can't simply pass the parameter to the method. I have tried many of the solutions available here and there, but no success.

```ts
getUser(id){
    this._http.get('http://localhost:53226/api/UserAPI/GetSpecificUser', id) // is there a simple way to do this?
    .subscribe((result: any) => {
    this.specificuser = result.json();
    console.log(this.specificuser);
    });
}
```

EDIT:

This is the method in my controller.

```
public UserModel GetSpecificUser(int id)
{
    var user = UserDB.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);

    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserModel>();
    });
    IMapper iMapper = config.CreateMapper();
    var destination = iMapper.Map<User, UserModel>(user);

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: It depends how the API is expecting that parameter. Body (unusual for a GET request, I think you'd have to use `_http.request` directly)? In what form? URL? Path or query parameter? Have you read [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/http)?

Comment: How do you want to send the parameter? as a queryString or pathParam?

Comment: I suggest you to read about query parameters and route/uri parameters

Comment: Sorry for the trouble guys! I am new to angular!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If your API is like `http://localhost:53226/api/UserAPI/GetSpecificUser/{userId}` use this

```
this._http.get(`http://localhost:53226/api/UserAPI/GetSpecificUser/${id}`)
```

(or similar technique)

Comment: @KevalJarsania this means that problem is on server side. First - what exactly is your api on your serwer? Update your question

Comment: @KevalJarsania look on your chrome console> network tab> and tell what request was send

Answer (score -3):

If i heard your question right so i will just tell you to convert the id into integer by using

```
this._http.get('http://localhost:53226/api/UserAPI/GetSpecificUser',parseInt(id))
```

Hope it gonna help you.

Answer (score -4):

Using post() could help

```
getUser(id){
   this._http.post('http://localhost:53226/api/UserAPI/GetSpecificUser', id)
   .pipe(map(result: any) => {
        this.specificuser = result.json();
        console.log(this.specificuser);
   });
}
```

Comment: If you have to *get* a user you must use *GET*, *POST* must be used to create a new content. Each HTTP method has a specific meaning.